# How to make a web service client for a web service that requires password digest

Tags: java, webservice-client, password-encryption

I want to build a web service client in Java to be deployed as part of a web application in weblogic. The web service that I want to consume requires password digest for the authentication mechanism.

I see that soapUI automatically creates this password digest along with a nonce and a timestamp. On the other hand, I haven't been able to find a Java library that can help me achieve the same thing.

Do you know any library that I can use for this? or maybe an algorithm that I can reuse so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel and do it from scratch.

Note: I know that it is possible to configure an authentication provider in weblogic for this, but unfortunately I can't rely on the application server configuration in the environment that I am using now.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question is off-topic but Spring is a well known application framework and Spring-WS can probably help you do accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know your technology stack on the server side (it's WS-Security? WCF?), but Apache CXF Client comes with good support for web services security: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html